# Create a localizable custom data attribute in ASP.Net MVC Core .Net6

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, custom-data-attribute

I'm currently using `.AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()` with plenty of success for localizing the DisplayAttribute Name and Description.

How can I create a custom attribute that can be localized in the same way? Using DotPeek, I could see that the DisplayAttribute uses an internal class named LocalizableString for its properties.

```
    internal class LocalizableString
    {
        #region Member fields

        private readonly string _propertyName;
        private Func<string?>? _cachedResult;
        private string? _propertyValue;

        [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties)]
        private Type? _resourceType;

        #endregion

        #region All Constructors

        public LocalizableString(string propertyName)
        {
            _propertyName = propertyName;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        public string? Value
        {
            get => _propertyValue;
            set
            {
                if (_propertyValue != value)
                {
                    ClearCache();
                    _propertyValue = value;
                }
            }
        }

        [DynamicallyAccessedMembers(DynamicallyAccessedMemberTypes.PublicProperties)]
        public Type? ResourceType
        {
            get => _resourceType;
            set
            {
                if (_resourceType != value)
                {
                    ClearCache();
                    _resourceType = value;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private void ClearCache()
        {
            _cachedResult = null;
        }


        public string? GetLocalizableValue()
        {
            if (_cachedResult == null)
            {
                // If the property value is null, then just cache that value
                // If the resource type is null, then property value is literal, so cache it
                if (_propertyValue == null || _resourceType == null)
                {
                    _cachedResult = () => _propertyValue;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Get the property from the resource type for this resource key
                    var property = _resourceType.GetRuntimeProperty(_propertyValue);

                    // We need to detect bad configurations so that we can throw exceptions accordingly
                    var badlyConfigured = false;

                    // Make sure we found the property and it's the correct type, and that the type itself is public
                    if (!_resourceType.IsVisible || property == null ||
                         property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                    {
                        badlyConfigured = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Ensure the getter for the property is available as public static
                        // TODO - check that GetMethod returns the same as old GetGetMethod()
                        // in all situations regardless of modifiers
                        var getter = property.GetMethod;
                        if (getter == null || !(getter.IsPublic && getter.IsStatic))
                        {
                            badlyConfigured = true;
                        }
                    }

                    // If the property is not configured properly, then throw a missing member exception
                    if (badlyConfigured)
                    {
                        string exceptionMessage = "error";// SR.Format(SR.LocalizableString_LocalizationFailed, _propertyName, _resourceType.FullName, _propertyValue);
                        _cachedResult = () => { throw new InvalidOperationException(exceptionMessage); };
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // We have a valid property, so cache the resource
                        _cachedResult = () => (string?)property!.GetValue(null, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the cached result
            return _cachedResult();
        }
        #endregion
        }
    }
```

It's not accessible, so I just duplicated the class. Then, I created my new attribute like this, also using the code I found for DisplayAttribute using DotPeek:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class HintAttribute : Attribute
    {
        private Type _resourceType;
        private LocalizableString _content = new LocalizableString(nameof(Content));

        public Type ResourceType
        {
            get => this._resourceType;
            set
            {
                if (!(this._resourceType != value))
                    return;
                this._resourceType = value;
                this._content.ResourceType = value;
            }
        }

        public string Content
        {
            get => this._content.Value;

            set
            {
                if (!(this._content.Value != value))
                    return;
                this._content.Value = value;
            }
        }

        public string GetContent() => this._content.GetLocalizableValue();
    }
```

This actually works great with one caveat...I need to specify the ResourceType like this:

```
[Hint(Content = "ResourceKey", ResourceType = typeof(MyResource))]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

I can get by with this, but I'd like my HintAttribute to use the same magic that the DisplayAttribute uses where you don't have to provide the ResourceType. It just looks in either the shared resource or the Model.en.resx file. I'm unable to simply set the ResourceType property because no code is generated on a Model.en.resx file. As a result, I can't use the same file for my HintAttribute resources. Any ideas?

Comment: In your HintAttribute, you do need to pass in ResourceType. Would it be helpful for you to look at [this link](https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/localizing-data-annotation-attributes-in-asp-net-core)?

Comment: I basically want to store my translations in the same resx file as for the Display attribute. I'm guessing some reflection is used to automatically set the ResourceType for MyModel to MyModel.en.resx which is why you don't have to specify it in the Display attribute. I'm just trying to find out exactly how that is done and do the same thing for my custom attribute.

Comment: `I'm guessing some reflection is used to automatically set the ResourceType for MyModel to MyModel.en.resx`, this may be due to your local language.